# Removing spurious pagebreak in index?

Tags: page-breaking, indexing

EDIT: To clarify my question: I am not looking for an index that will start without a page break; I, rather, want an index where I manually would take care of the page break.

Say you've inserted a ton of `\clearpage`s, to make sure that the "next" page starts on pg 37. Now you want to insert the index "here", at page 37 - so you type `\printindex[names]` there - and, surprise - the index now starts at page 38, because the index decided to enter one more `\clearpage` `:/` And that means now you have to go back, and re-enter ammount of `\clearpage`s, so they match to page N-1; so that along with the extra pagebreak, the index will start where at page N. This I'd see as an unnecessary complication.

Second, let's say you don't want to use the default section title of `\printindex`; you'd rather use `\section*`. The easiest thing to think of (without knowing any better), is to suppress the default index heading (*in this case, since the example is for `\printindex` from `index` package, that would be in `\newindex` command*):

```
\newindex{names}{ndx}{nnd}{}  % instead of: {names}{ndx}{nnd}{Name Index}
```

... (which does indeed suppress the default index heading) - and then, instead of that heading, one would type `\section*{Name Index}` followed by a `\printindex[names]`. Obviously, if `\printindex` inserts its own pagebreak, then this approach won't work, since the section title and the first page of the index will be on different pages - which is precisely what the MWE in this question demonstrates....

---

<s>Damn it, I'm really starting to hate Latex `:/`</s>  naah... `:)`

Take a look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{book}


% must load index before hyperref, else no hyperlinks!
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{trace}

% declare new index files
\newindex{names}{ndx}{nnd}{Name Index}
\newindex{titles}{tdx}{tnd}{Title Index}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{trace}

% expandable modulo operation
\def\truncdiv#1#2{((#1-(#2-1)/2)/#2)}
\def\moduloop#1#2{(#1-\truncdiv{#1}{#2}*#2)}
\def\modulo#1#2{\number\numexpr\moduloop{#1}{#2}\relax}


% needed to generate index files
\newcounter{ct}
\def\modme{10}

% generate names (.nnd) index file
\newwrite\tempnnd
\immediate\openout\tempnnd=\jobname.nnd
\immediate\write\tempnnd{\protect\noexpand\begin{theindex}}

\forLoop[1]{0}{255}{ct}{
    \immediate\write\tempnnd{%
      \protect\noexpand\item Surname\thect, Name\thect, %
      %\protect\noexpand\hyperpage{\thect}
      % hyperlink all to page 1, 
      % to avoid Latex complaining:
      \protect\noexpand\hyperpage{1} %
    }
    \ifnum\modulo\thect\modme=0
      \immediate\write\tempnnd{}
      \immediate\write\tempnnd{\protect\noexpand\indexspace}
      \immediate\write\tempnnd{}
    \else
    \fi
}
\immediate\write\tempnnd{\protect\noexpand\end{theindex}}
\immediate\closeout\tempnnd

% generate titles (.tnd) index file
\newwrite\temptnd
\immediate\openout\temptnd=\jobname.tnd
\immediate\write\temptnd{\protect\noexpand\begin{theindex}}

\forLoop{0}{255}{ct}{
    \immediate\write\temptnd{%
      \protect\noexpand\item \noexpand\emph {Title of Work\thect}, %
      %\protect\noexpand\hyperpage{\thect}
      % hyperlink all to page 1, 
      % to avoid Latex complaining:
      \protect\noexpand\hyperpage{1} %
    }
    \ifnum\modulo\thect\modme=0
      \immediate\write\temptnd{}
      \immediate\write\temptnd{\protect\noexpand\indexspace}
      \immediate\write\temptnd{}
    \else
    \fi
}
\immediate\write\temptnd{\protect\noexpand\end{theindex}}
\immediate\closeout\temptnd


\begin{document}

\clearpage

\section*{Test 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test 1}

\phantomsection % NOTE NO PAGEBREAK PRESENT AROUND HERE!
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Name Index} \traceon
\printindex[names] \traceoff

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title Index} % master TOC and PDF bookmark
\printindex[titles] % the title index

\end{document}
```

The first two pages of the output are:

[image: test.png]

Generated with:

```
montage -bordercolor LimeGreen -border 1 -density 100 test.pdf[0] test.pdf[1] -geometry +2+2 -tile 2x1 test.png
```

My question is:

Can someone explain to me why there a pagebreak before the Name Index section - and how do I remove it?

As seen in the MWE, I even tried tracing for it:

```
$ grep -C10 'Surname0' b.log
{into \Hy@temp=macro:->}
{\ifx}
{true}
{\else}
{blank space  }
{\relax}

\item ->\par \hangindent 40\p@                 <= \item
{\par}                                         <= \par (?)
@firstpass
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 Surname0, Name0, []0[]    <= typeset Surname0
@\par via @@0 b=0 p=-10000 d=100
@@1: line 1.2- t=100 -> @@0

{changing \hangindent=40.0pt}
{into \hangindent=0.0pt}
%% goal height=476.5225, max depth=5.5         <= pagebreak?!
% t=0.0 g=476.5225 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#       <=    WHERE FROM??
{vertical mode: \hangindent}
{changing \hangindent=0.0pt}
{into \hangindent=40.0pt}
```

... but I simply don't understand which command would cause a new page **after** the first name is typeset ?! And if the pagebreak happened after `Surname0` got typeset, why isn't `Surname0` on first page ??!

Comment: An index in the `book` documentclass is set as a chapter and issues `\clearpage` *before* creating the heading. To see this, search for the definitions of `theindex` in [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and `\twocolumn` (called by the `theindex` environment) in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx).

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Werner - not knowing any better, I started by hacking `\renewenvironment{theindex}` and `\def\@showidx` from `index.sty`; that could have been quite a dead end for me without your pointer! I managed to remove the pagebreak (post [below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61090/2595)) - however, that also messes up the twocolumn layout of the index `:)` Still, great to know where the pagebreak was initiated from (I just wish I could debug myself to those kinds of conclusions). Many thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems quite abstract, because it's quite rare to have an index start without a page break. However, here is a possibility. Since you don't want page breaks, it's necessary to avoid any automatism in index generation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[noautomatic,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% declare new index files
\makeindex[name=names,title=Name Index,intoc]
\makeindex[name=titles,title=Title Index,intoc]
\indexsetup{level=\section*} % no page break with sections

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% generate fake index entries
\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<200
  \index[names]{Surname\number\count255, Name\number\count255}
  \index[titles]{Title of Work\number\count255}
  \advance\count255 1
\repeat

\clearpage

\phantomsection
\section*{Test 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Test 1}

\printindex[names]
\printindex[titles]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @egreg - I'm never keen on switching packages; however your answer code works fine, and behaves as I expect it to - so I'll be switching from package `index` to package `imakeidx` `:)` Btw, I appreciate this example a lot - it was nearly impossible for me to find examples that would compare code for `index` and code for `imakeidx` (_so fx. one can see that `\newindex` from `index` corresponds to `\makeindex` from `imakeidx`_). Many thanks again - cheers!

Comment: Why is it necessary to avoid the automation, though? Either `texindy` is ran via `\write18` and the resulting `.ind` is included into the page immediately, or I run `texindy` manually and the resulting `.ind` is included into the page in the next run. I don't see the difference, but there has to be one, doesn't there?

Comment: @Witiko If there's no page break, entries defined in the last page won't appear in the index.

Comment: Wouldn't making the `\write`s in the definition of `\index` `\immediate` fix this?

Comment: @Witiko No, the page numbers are known only during the output routine.

Answer (score 3):

write into the preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{multicol}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{theindex}
  {{\huge\indexname}\par%
   \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
   \parindent\z@
   \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
   \let\item\@idxitem
   \begin{multicols}{2}}
  {\end{multicols}}
\makeatother
...
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @Herbert - that looked really good, but when I add that snippet to the preamble of the MWE in OP (right after the `\immediate\closeout\temptnd` line), I get "`! LaTeX Error: \begin{theindex} on input line 1 ended by \end{multicols}.`" Could it be due to a typo of sorts? Cheers!

Comment: I edited my answer. It works for me with your MWE

Comment: Many thanks for the edit, @Herbert - now it works great; as a bonus, the sectioning is now separate (`{\huge\indexname}\par`), so I can remove it and use a `\section*` instead... While this answer is the one matching the question more closely (_it still uses `index`, with addition of `multicol`_), I'll keep the accept with [@egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61092/2595), because it allows for comparison between packages `index` and `imakeidx`, which I thought was impossible to find. Many thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to @Werner (in OP comments) for the most crucial pointer!

Unfortunately, instead of going through `book.cls` and `latex.ltx`, I - not knowing any better - tried to look at `index.sty`; but that doesn't reveal anything but a couple of `\clearpage`s (which should run *after*, not before the index is typeset).

The definitions of `theindex` and `\twocolumn` can be easily confirmed with `texdef`:

```
$ texdef -t latex -c book -p index \theindex -f
\theindex first defined in "book.cls".

\theindex:
\long macro:->\edef \indexname {\the \@nameuse {idxtitle@\@indextype }}\if@twocolumn \@restonecolfalse \else \@restonecoltrue \fi \columnseprule \z@ \columnsep 35\p@ \twocolumn [\@makeschapterhead {\indexname }\ifx \index@prologue \@empty \else \index@prologue \bigskip \fi ]\@mkboth {\MakeUppercase \indexname }{\MakeUppercase \indexname }\thispagestyle {plain}\parindent \z@ \parskip \z@ \@plus .3\p@ \relax \let \item \@idxitem 

2$ texdef -t latex -c book -p index \twocolumn -f
\twocolumn is defined by (La)TeX.

\twocolumn:
macro:->\clearpage \global \columnwidth \textwidth \global \advance \columnwidth -\columnsep \global \divide \columnwidth \tw@ \global \hsize \columnwidth \global \linewidth \columnwidth \global \@twocolumntrue \global \@firstcolumntrue \col@number \tw@ \@ifnextchar [\@topnewpage \@floatplacement
```

(<sub>NB: I was staring at `\twocolumn` for a couple of minutes, before realizing the `\clearpage` is the first token there `:)`</sub>)

Thus, we can finally insert this redefinition before the indexes are printed:

```
....
\makeatletter
\def \twocolumn {%
  %\clearpage
  \global\columnwidth\textwidth
  \global\advance\columnwidth-\columnsep
  \global\divide\columnwidth\tw@
  \global\hsize\columnwidth
  \global\linewidth\columnwidth
  \global\@twocolumntrue
  \global\@firstcolumntrue
  \col@number \tw@
  \@ifnextchar [\@topnewpage\@floatplacement
}
\makeatother

\phantomsection % NOTE NO PAGEBREAK PRESENT AROUND HERE!
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Name Index} %\traceon
\printindex[names] %\traceoff

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title Index} % 
\printindex[titles] % 

\end{document}
```

... and indeed - finally the page break is gone! However, there is another problem now - even if you suppress the title like this:

```
\newindex{names}{ndx}{nnd}{}
```

... still the layout of the index will be messed up - given the index is typeset in two column mode - seemingly, the "`\section*{Test 1}`" will "push" the left column down - and so it won't look good:

[image: test.png]

... but at least the page break is gone `:)`