# Problem with option "noclearpage" of \indexsetup, imakeidx

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I'm using the package `imakeidx` in order to generate the *indexes* for my document, but i get an issue when i use the option `noclearpage` being that the index is not **printed** (or it don't print all entries - *incomplete index*).

I use this option to avoid the index in the next page `\clearpage`.

### Problem

With

```
\indexsetup{level=\section,toclevel=section}
```

works perfect! but the index pass to the next page, and with

```
\indexsetup{level=\section,toclevel=section,noclearpage}
```

the *index* is not printed.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{level=\section,toclevel=section,noclearpage} %
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{F}
a\index{first}
b\index{second}
\section{G}
c\index{third} d\index{four}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I don't understand what is the problem?

### Edit

I tried to add the `nonewpage` option suggested in the first answer, but the problem worsens because not even the `.idx` file is generated inclusive after of run *repeatedly* with `pdflatex` (Neither `pdflatex --enable-write18` nor `pdflatex -shell-escape` work) generating a *`.log`* like (part)

```
...

No file indexsetupproblem.ind.

Package imakeidx Warning: Remember to run (pdf)latex again after calling
(imakeidx)                `makeindex indexsetupproblem.idx'.

[1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
\indexentry{first}{1}
\indexentry{second}{1}
\indexentry{third}{1}
\indexentry{four}{1}
]

...
```

It seems that to add the `nonewpage` option inhibits definitely the creation of the `.idx` file (the file is created but *empty*).

Comment: I fear, this is not the right command here. The `noclearpage` is meant for multiple indices. You have to prevent the page break before writing `\printindex`!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61089

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**:

As my previous answer did not work, I asked Enrico Gregorio (the author and maintainer of `imakeidx`) for help. As he told me, this solution needs a fix of the package, if the option `splitindex` is not loaded. You find this fix in between `\makeatletter\makeatother`. Thanks to egreg. I mark this CW.

---

> `nonewpage` inhibits the new page command to be issued when using an
>   article type document class and multiple indices are being typeset. We
>   don’t see why someone would use multiple indices in an article (except
>   possibly for package documentations, which usually provide a macro
>   index and a list of changes). (egreg 2013, `imakeidx` documentation)

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{level=\section,toclevel=section} %
\makeindex
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\imki@putindex}
{\immediate}
{\ifimki@disableautomatic\else\immediate}
{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\imki@putindex}
{\endcsname}
{\endcsname\fi}
{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{F}
    a\index{first}
    b\index{second}
    \section{G}
    c\index{third} d\index{four}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but if i add the `nonewpage` option the `.idx` file isn't generated (it *stays* empty).

Comment: @skpblack Now it works.

Comment: It works, but disables the *automatic* way.

Comment: @skpblack which automatic way?

Comment: I must run `makeindex` manually

Comment: But I have not changed anything regarding this topic. How did you do that with your MWE? Should be the very same procedure.